# max memory redis heroku django

Tags: python, django, heroku, redis

I am trying to add a video upload to a task using django and celery + redis. The videos will be a maximum of 3mb but It seems passing the video in memory is problematic and reaches the limit for redis.

How can I find what the max memory limit is for redis?

This is what the video upload looks like:

```
@csrf_exempt
def tag_location(request):
    if request.FILES.__contains__('file'):
        image = request.FILES['file'].read()
    else:
        image = None

    if request.FILES.__contains__('video-file'):
        video = request.FILES['video-file'].read()
    else:
        video = None

    tasks.tag_location.delay(image,video)

    return JsonResponse({'response': 1})
```

The task is 100% working just sometimes the files are too large. Is there a way to just pass a file path for the video/image to redis rather than reading through the file and passing it through memory?

Comment: Open a connection to your Redis database and run the command `CONFIG GET maxmemory`. Which Redis database are you using?

Comment: If you are using Heroku Redis, the memory sizes for each plan are also indicated on the addons page: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis

Answer (score 2):

The `maxmemory` configuration directive is used to configure the Redis to use a specified amount of memory for the data set.

**Finding the maximum memory limit:**

To find out the maximum memory limit of a running Redis server, you need to use the `CONFIG GET` command. The `CONFIG GET` command is generally used to read the configuration parameters of a running Redis server. 
It takes a single argument and returns all the configuration parameters matching this parameter as a list of key-value pairs.

Example:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG GET maxmemory # gets maximum memory limit of redis server
```

64 bit systems have default value of `maxmemory` as `0` (zero) resulting into no memory limits.
32 bit systems use an implicit memory limit of `3GB`.

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG GET maxmemory # output on my 64 bit system
1) "maxmemory"
2) "0"
```

**Modifying the maximum memory limit:**

To modify the maximum memory limit of the redis server, you can set the `maxmemory` configuration directive using the `redis.conf` file, or by using the `CONFIG SET` command at runtime.

For example in order to configure a memory limit of 500 megabytes, the following directive can be used inside the redis.conf file.

```
maxmemory 500mb
```

Comment: As I see the question is about Heroku redis specifically. And AFAICS `CONFIG GET` command unfortunatelly doesn't work with their's CLI. Not on the Hobby Dev plan at least